# "Escaping" nightmare

Tags: bash, escaping, special-characters, expect

I have been trying to put the following into a bash script:

```
scp /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Spiceworks/data/configurations/LA_$(date +%F)-firewall-5520 "sf-mlawler@10.21.1.212:/home/sf-mlawler/SBOX_Automation/SBOX_Dumps/08\ -\ Security/Firewalls"
```

...which works as expected via command line.

When I try to place it in a script, I'm obviously going to have to double escape the spaces, anything else? I'm unable to have success with the multitude of variations I've tried.

I would think:

```
scp /cygdrive/c/Program\\ Files\\ \(x86\)/Spiceworks/data/configurations/LA_\$(date\ +%F)-firewall-5520 "sf-mlawler@10.21.1.212:/home/sf-mlawler/SBOX_Automation/SBOX_Dumps/08\\ \\-\\ Security/Firewalls"
```

...would work, but it doesn't. Any suggestions, before I go grey and bald? Thanks

I wont waste the space with all variations I've tried, but I will say I have tried escaping almost everything and basically nothing and many in between with no success. When I receive a "No such file or Directory" I obviously escape until the file actually resolves, but even when I do not get a path error, the command is not successfully completing.

I do understand this is quite a specific case, but I imagine it will help others in the future: escaping spaces, in a bash script, using embedded `expect` (I have tested with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang and the embedded `expect using expect -c ' .... '` as well as `#!/usr/bin/expect` using a simple `spawn scp` command with no change.

EDIT (Based on responses):

I should have mentioned I have tried quoting it...

Quoting the first (host) part gives me the error

> can't read "(date +%F)": no such variable
>       while executing

```
"spawn scp "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Spiceworks/data/configurations/LA_$(date +%F)-firewall-5520" "sf-mlawler@10.21.1.212:/home/sf-mlawler/SBOX_..."
```

...it is not a variable, it is a function giving me the current date in the format `year-month-day`

Quoting the destination section without escaping anything gives me the error

```
scp: ambiguous target
```

Comment: Why don't you quote it?

Comment: i was looking up nightmare and found this, though, and it is however a topic of much confusion for people - it is pretty important that everyone reading this should stick to Slomojo's advice to not ever attempting to over escape strings and get them into variables asap! (before you click away) You wouldn't stick your hand in the blender when you have a perfectly good spoon would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick it in quotes and stop hitting yourself, as @that_other_guy said, you cannot, and shouldn't try and escape twice, wherever you got that idea, disregard it as a source of information. (my guess is it came from *"thin air"*)

```
scp "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Spiceworks/data/configurations/LA_$(date +%F)-firewall-5520" "sf-mlawler@10.21.1.212:/home/sf-mlawler/SBOX_Automation/SBOX_Dumps/08 - Security/Firewalls"
```

You could even give yourself some helpers:

```
export PROGFILESx86="/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)"
export SPICEWORKS_CONFIGS="${PROGFILESx86}/Spiceworks/data/configurations"
```

(add them to `.bashrc`, exec it.) and then do:

```
scp "${SPICEWORKS_CONFIGS}/LA_$(date +%F)-firewall-5520" "sf-mlawler@10.21.1.212:/home/sf-mlawler/SBOX_Automation/SBOX_Dumps/08 - Security/Firewalls"
```

I'd also be concerned the the files you are attempting to `scp` actually exist, wrap it up in a condition to verify they're there, it only makes sense when you're auto-generating a filename.

```
firewall_config="${SPICEWORKS_CONFIGS}/LA_$(date +%F)-firewall-5520"

if [ -e "${firewall_config}" ]
    then
        scp "${firewall_config}" "sf-mlawler@10.21.1.212:/home/sf-mlawler/SBOX_Automation/SBOX_Dumps/08 - Security/Firewalls"
    else         
        echo "File doesn't exist: ${firewall_config}"
fi
```

## Update:

Since you've updated your question, it's obviously the `date` call that's giving you the biggest problem, again, indirection saves you doing bizarre escape-char-yoga, just get the result into a var and use that.

```
fw_date=$(date +%F)
firewall_config="${SPICEWORKS_CONFIGS}/LA_${fw_date}-firewall-5520"
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I like the idea of using helpers, but adding them to the .bashrc isn't an option. I am playing around with it now and pretty sure that will be my solution. Thanks for the help

Comment: `.bashrc` is just a suggestion, and really only applies to getting `Program Files (x86)` aliased off globally, since you may have to deal with it a lot from the command line.

Comment: @TryTryAgain since you're doing all this in a script anyway, you really should get in the habit of setting up your variables up front, and then stuff is just much easier. Just remember to quote the variable usage `"${varname}"` rather than `$varname` so that vars which expand to expressions with spaces aren't interpreted as multiple arguments.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the update, that's exactly what I'm doing. Great advice to just make all these pieces into variables. Lesson learned :)

Comment: Happy to help @TryTryAgain, generally the only problem you can't solve with more indirection, is too much indirection ;)

Answer (score 3):

The same command that worked on your bash shell should work the same in your bash script. You shouldn't and cannot escape it twice.

If it doesn't work, make sure you're testing the script from the same terminal, ensure that the script contents and your command is identical, then paste the output from your terminal when you do:

```
$ scp /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Spiceworks/data/configurations/LA_$(date +%F)-firewall-5520 "sf-mlawler@10.21.1.212:/home/sf-mlawler/SBOX_Automation/SBOX_Dumps/08\ -\ Security/Firewalls"
(successful scp output here)
$ cat testscript
(testscript contents here, should be identical to above scp command)
$ bash testscript
(unsuccessful script/scp output here)
```

Comment: Escaping twice is the onlay way I get around the error "scp: ambiguous target" and I have read it from many sites referring to escaping spaces and using scp including accepted answers on SO. What makes you say I "cannot" @Slomojo . maybe not best practice, but it works?

Comment: Ok, so you "can" but you should not, you're just creating issues for yourself in the future when you try and solve problems in this way.  -- and when I say "can" in quotes, you're not escaping twice, you're you're escaping the `\\ ` so that it becomes a literal `\ ` that's then used as a normal escape in a subsequent processing, the point is it's convoluted and that's why you should avoid it.   Keep it simple,

Comment: @TryTryAgain You're referring to escaping the scp target file twice. That's unrelated to the question.